# Detecting horizontal lines in homework using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to detect the underlines where students write their answers in the homework, but I cannot get Hough Line Transform to work. It is detecting way to many lines and if I increase thresholds, it will only detect vertical lines. Is there any other method to do this?

This is the code I have based on another post:

```
gray = cv2.imread(image_path + '000003.png')
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('edges-50-150.jpg',edges)

minLineLength=100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=10,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=80)

a,b,c = lines.shape

for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(gray, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imwrite('houghlines5.jpg',gray)
```

When I run the code above I get these lines: [Hough Transform Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjRvQ.jpg)

Edit: original image - [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SvBA.jpg)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please post your input image.

Comment: Yes please provide a sample image

Comment: Try to apply some filters before applying ```HoughLinesP()``` to extract horizontal lines more properly. I'd recommend to apply threshold, do some morphological transformations to erase noise and make lines thicker and apply appropriate Gabor filter on top of that. It's possible that Gabor filter alone would make the job for You, but You don't know unless You'll try it.

Comment: As @stateMachine noted above, please post the original image rather than just the result. That's standard practice for image processing problems; having the original image is a big help in spotting what may be going wrong. Try filtering to find horizontal edges rather than using Canny. A simple Sobel filter oriented to find horizontal edge pixels may help.

Comment: @stateMachine Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow, but I have added the original image. Thank you for any help!